# "Ви́падок" чи "випа́док"?

Tags: наголос

Скажіть, будь ласка, який із варіантів наголосу є правильним?

1. "Ви́падок" - наголос на першому складі
2. "Випа́док" - на другому.

Чи можуть бути правильними обидва варіанти?

Comment: Відповідь на запитання легко знайти [простим пошуком](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=випадок+наголос). Якщо ви запропоновані варіанти бачили, то варто вказувати, чим вони не підходять.

Comment: @bytebuster — прошу вибачити неофіта, я поквапився із запитанням, адже відповідь дійсно була на прверхні пошуку. Чи варто мені видалити це запитання зараз?

Comment: Запитання вже отримало відповідь, і тому видалення знищило б зусилля, яке доклав інший користувач. Краще залишити, як є.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно лише **ви́падок**.

На мій погляд, це одна з найпоширеніших помилок в усному мовленні. Вона є настільки частою, що порою й сам заплутуєшся, як правильно. Та я вигадав просте мнемонічне правило: коли чую слово "випАдок", то згадую співзвучне слово "упАдок", яке викликає нагативне відчуття і тому дає зрозуміти, що наголос упав не на той склад.